# Can't change the display value of Data Grid View cell programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I try to set the value of cell in my Data Grid View manually by code, however, when running there are nothing change. I print the value of these cell to console and the cells ' value are set, but they're not display.

```
        `TheLoaiList = BUSTheLoai.Instance.GetAllTheLoai();
        TheLoaiGrid.DataSource = TheLoaiList;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in TheLoaiGrid.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells["SoTuaSach"].Value = "10";
            Console.WriteLine(row.Cells["SoTuaSach"].Value);
            i++;
        }`
```

Comment: in which method, you have written this code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be on the right track. Binding the `TheLoaiGrid.DataSource` to the `TheLoaiList` that's *good* because you can change what's in the `DataGridView` by changing `TheLoaiList`. The next step you might want to try is making the *items* in the list work the same way (using binding) so that when you do your loop, you can modify the *data* not the `DataGridViewRow`:

```
foreach (TheLoai theLoai in TheLoaiList)
{
    theLoai.SoTuaSach = "10"; 
}
```

---

For this to work, it requires a small change to the class that represents your row items. Suppose you  defined `TheLoaiList` this way:

```
BindingList<TheLoai> TheLoaiList { get; } = new BindingList<TheLoai>();
```

Then here's an example of how to automatically notify the `DataGridView` when a property changes using `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
// using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
class TheLoai : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _soTuaSach = string.Empty;
    public string SoTuaSach
    {
        get => _soTuaSach;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_soTuaSach, value))
            {
                _soTuaSach = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    string _column2 = string.Empty;
    public string Column2
    {
        get => _column2;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_column2, value))
            {
                _column2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

Here's a minimal working [sample](https://github.com/IVSoftware/theloailist.git) if you want to try this out.

[image: screenshot]